# How can I center this button horizontally to my page?

Tags: html, sharepoint

I am using SharePoint, and I want to center this to the page horizontally. I am constrained by the 
limitations of SharePoint at my job. I am using a Scrip Editor in a Web Part. I have tried adding 
line-height: 0; & display:inline-block; margin:0 auto; width: 200px;

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   .dropbtn { 
    background-color: transparent !important;
    padding: none;
    font-size: 0px;
    border: none;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-Left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    }

   .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ffffff;
    outline: none !important;
    }

   .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
   /* The following will affect sub menu color*/
    background-color: #78AB46   ;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0  !important;
    }

   .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
   }

   .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #C0D9AF;
   }
   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

   </style>
   </head>
    <body>

    <div class="dropdown">

    <button class="dropbtn"><img 
    src="https://assets.webiconspng.com/uploads/2017/09/Buttons-PNG-Image-36425.png" width="700"  /> 
    </button>

    <!-- Change link by placing inbetween >< -->
    <!-- Copy <a href="#">Link 1</a> to add a new line -->

    <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Link 1</a>
       <a href="#">Link 2</a>
       <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class `.dropdown`  remove `display:inline-block` and add `margin:auto` and the width you want to set (based on your code it's 700) `width:700px;`

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    width:200px;
    margin:auto;
    background: #ffffff;
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Check this example (I changed your button width to 200px for demonstration): https://jsfiddle.net/uocwk4br/

Comment: I see what you did, but when I do it in SharePoint it doesn't work. Not sure if this is something that SharePoint limits?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code as below.

```
<style>
.dropbtn { 
    background-color: transparent !important;
    padding: none;
    font-size: 0px;
    border: none;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-Left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ffffff;
    outline: none !important;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    /* The following will affect sub menu color*/
    background-color: #78AB46   ;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0  !important;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #C0D9AF;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

</style>
<center>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">
        <img src="https://assets.webiconspng.com/uploads/2017/09/Buttons-PNG-Image-36425.png" width="700"  /> 
    </button>
    <!-- Change link by placing inbetween >< -->
    <!-- Copy <a href="#">Link 1</a> to add a new line -->
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
</center>
```